# How do I refresh a label in a tkinter window so it has the value of a label?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

So I'm writing a program that makes a bubble sort to sort baby names. The program requires 2 users to enter a rating out of 10 for the name on the open tab. However I can't find any way to update the window when the user presses the enter button I've got.

```
from tkinter import *
BoyList = [['a',0],['b',0],['c',0],['d',0],['e',0],['f',0],['h',0],['i',0],['j',0]]
GirlList = [['a',0],['b',0],['c',0],['d',0],['e',0],['f',0],['h',0],['i',0],['j',0]]
```

currently the lists are full of place holders

```
Number1 = 0
Number2 = 0
Count = 0

def MainMenu():
    Menu = Tk()
    Menu.title('MainMenu')
    MenuLab = Label(Menu, text = 'Main Menu')
    MenuLab.pack()
    BoyButton = Button(Menu, text = 'Select a boy name', command = lambda Menu=Menu:NameRuleBoy(Menu))
    BoyButton.pack()
    GirlButton = Button(Menu, text = 'Select a girl name', command = lambda Menu=Menu:NameRuleGirl(Menu))
    GirlButton.pack()
    QuitButton = Button(Menu, text = 'Quit', command = lambda Menu=Menu:QuitButton(Menu))
    QuitButton.pack()
    Menu.mainloop()

def QuitButton(Menu):
    Menu.destroy()

def GirlBackButt(RuleGirlName):
    RuleGirlName.destroy()
    MainMenu()

def NameRuleGirl(Menu):
    Menu.destroy()
    RuleGirlName = Tk()
    RuleGirlName.title('Naming rules')
    RulLab = Label(RuleGirlName, text = 'When a name comes up rate the name out of ten (ten being like it a lot)')
    RulLab.pack()
    ContinueButt = Button(RuleGirlName, text = 'Continue', command = lambda RuleGirlName=RuleGirlName:NameGirl(RuleGirlName))
    ContinueButt.pack()
    BackButton = Button(RuleGirlName, text = 'Back', command = lambda RuleGirlName=RuleGirlName:GirlBackButt(RuleGirlName))
    BackButton.pack()
    RuleGirlName.mainloop()

def NameGirl(RuleGirlName):
    RuleGirlName.destroy()
    GirlName = Tk()
    NameLabel = Label(GirlName, text = GirlList[0][0])
    NameLabel.pack()
    ParentLabel1 = Label(GirlName, text = 'Parent 1 put score here:')
    ParentLabel1.pack()
    Entry1 = Entry(GirlName)
    Entry1.pack()
    ParentLabel2 = Label(GirlName, text = 'Parent 2 put score here:')
    ParentLabel2.pack()
    Entry2 = Entry(GirlName)
    Entry2.pack()
    EnterButton = Button(GirlName, text = 'Enter', command = lambda GirlNamme=GirlName:GetButt(Entry1,Entry2,GirlName,Count))
    EnterButton.pack()
    GirlName.mainloop()

def GetButt(Entry1, Entry2,GirlName,Count):
    Number1 = Entry1.get()
    Number2 = Entry2.get()
    Number1 = int(Number1)
    Number2 = int(Number2)
    print(Number1,Number2)
    WindowUpdate(Count)
    return (Number1,Number2)

def WindowUpdate(Count):
    Count += 1
    GirlList[Count][0]

MainMenu()
```

I have included the code for all of my Tkinter windows if it is needed to help me with my code. On a side: could you help me know why all my calculations in my functions are returning 0 when I test them outside my functions?

Comment: there are a few problems but one big issue is you are calling `Tk()` several times. Instead of doing this you should be using `Tk()` one time to start your application and use `Topelevel()` for each new window.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have tried your suggestion and when executed I now have an extra window when i use one of my buttons. Do you know a reason for why this is?

Comment: It works on my end I will review you question soon if no one else has. There are several issues to address.

Comment: Can you add some detail as to what it is you are expecting your program to do once you press the `EnterButton`? Currently it is not doing much and likely not doing what you think it should be doing. Are you wanting the window to close or for it to have the next name presented?

Comment: When the  'EnterButton'  is pressed it is meant to take the numbers that have been entered into the entry boxes, find the average of the two and then put them in the second variable of the currently selected item of the list, then update it so there is the next name in the list is presented in the label. So in short it is to have the next name presented

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get everything working without using a class because you have not used a class in your example. However the code was getting a bit messy and `global` was everywhere...

We need to be able to keep track of what the last index was check in the `GirlList` and to update the `Toplevel()` window after you press the submit button. This is best achieved with a class and we can avoid the use of global at the same time.

In my below example the root window will open a toplevel window and display the first option. Once the submit button is pressed it will process the average and update the list. Then it will clear the entry fields and update to the next list item.

Here is my answer using a class example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.GirlList = [['a',0],['b',0],['c',0],['d',0],['e',0],['f',0],['h',0],['i',0],['j',0]]
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('MainMenu')
        self.gname_x = 0

        MenuLab = tk.Label(self.master, text='Main Menu')
        MenuLab.pack()
        GirlButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='Select a girl name', command=self.NameRuleGirl)
        GirlButton.pack()
        QuitButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='Quit', command=self.QuitButton)
        QuitButton.pack()

    def QuitButton(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def NameGirl(self):
        if self.gname_x <= len(self.GirlList):
            self.top = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.name_label = tk.Label(self.top, text=self.GirlList[self.gname_x][0])
            self.name_label.pack()
            tk.Label(self.top, text='Parent 1 put score here:').pack()
            self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(self.top)
            self.Entry1.pack()
            tk.Label(self.top, text='Parent 2 put score here:').pack()
            self.Entry2 = tk.Entry(self.top)
            self.Entry2.pack()
            tk.Button(self.top, text='Enter', command=self.update_girl_name).pack()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "You have already reviewed the girl names!")

    def update_girl_name(self):
        valid_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
        if self.Entry1.get().strip() in valid_list and self.Entry2.get().strip() in valid_list: 
            average_vote = (int(self.Entry1.get().strip()) + int(self.Entry2.get().strip())) / 2
            self.GirlList[self.gname_x][1] = average_vote
            self.gname_x += 1
            if self.gname_x < len(self.GirlList):
                self.name_label.config(text=self.GirlList[self.gname_x][0])
                self.Entry1.delete(0, "end")
                self.Entry2.delete(0, "end")
            else:
                self.top.destroy()
            print(self.GirlList)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Only numbers 1 through 10 are valid!")
            self.top.tkraise()
            self.Entry1.delete(0, "end")
            self.Entry2.delete(0, "end")

    def NameRuleGirl(self):
        answer = messagebox.askquestion("Naming rules", "When a name comes up rate the name out of ten.\n(ten being like it a lot and 1 being not at all).\n\n Do you wish to continue?")
        if answer == "yes":
            self.NameGirl()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    MyApp(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```